# Cron Job email find: missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, cron, plesk

I'm setting up a webserver with Plesk on Ubuntu 18.04 and I would like to use a part of the space I've available to store security footage. I succeeded in automatically uploading the photos and videos to the correct folder, but the problem is that they are not automatically removed, so that the server is full of security images. I upload the footages to a folder on the server that is also available from the internet (secured). I did some research on the internet to a cron job that automatically deleted the files older than 7 days where I found this:

```
find /var/www/vhosts/path to files/* -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

I also found that you can name a file to, for example: `delete-files` and which can be executed with crontab -e. (Yes, I made it executable;-)
I added this cron to run every hour and stated that I received notifications from the cron. Now, however, I get the following output: `` find: missing argument to `-exec ' ``

Is there anything else that I need to share? Like logs?

Comment: This technically speaking isn't a programming question, and should be over at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux , **imho**. Anyway, show us the actual crontab file's content ...

Comment: @tink --  One *could* argue that just because it's command line, doesn't mean that it wouldn't work inside a bash or shell script ..  It technically has structure, and syntax and can be used in a stand alone program / script.  I respectfully disagree :)

Comment: @Zak - feel free to argue ;) ... by that logic an `ls` w/ options might be programming, too. Where do you draw the line, and what, in your opinion, belongs over at unix? :)  Btw, HTML has structure, too ... is that a programming language? I don't think so ;)

Comment: Below is the content that's for the cron inside the crontab file:
`MAILTO="info@domain.com"
0      *       *       *       *       /var/www/vhosts/path to correct file/delete-files`

And this is now the content of the 'delete-files' file:
`find /var/www/vhosts/path to correct foler/ -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;`

Comment: By the way, I used this blog post: [https://www.maketecheasier.com/delete-old-files-in-a-folder-automatically-in-linux/](https://www.maketecheasier.com/delete-old-files-in-a-folder-automatically-in-linux/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change `find /var/www/vhosts/path to files/* -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;`

to

```
find /var/www/vhosts/path to files/ -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

the `*` is unnecessary in the path

---

Can you try this as well?

```
find /var/www/vhosts/path to files/ -mtime +7  | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, I still get the ```find: missing argument to `-exec' ``` error in my mailbox.

Comment: Is there any way to exclude some files/paths?